# SQL query from _subscribers is not retrieving any records

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I have below SQL query in Automation:

```sql
select top(10) 
  emailaddress
, dateunsubscribed
, status
, subscriberkey
, subscriberid 
from _subscribers
```

It doesn't populate any records in Data Extension while All Subscriber has lot of records?

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a prefix of "ENT" if running the query from a child Business Unit.

`FROM ENT._subscribers`

Comment: If i copy paste the same automation to production, do i need to remove ENT. from my sql?

Comment: I would do it this way and it will work

Comment: @krishnakundan it will still work if you keep or remove the ENT. when moving to production, assuming production is at the enterprise level.

Comment: @Tyler, How to check whether Production is at the enterprose level or not?